# Repetitive code for TextBox_LostFocus for multiple textboxes need to be cut down to one function

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling, uwp-xaml

I have a xaml page with multiple textboxes. For every textbox, there is a TextBox_LostFocus event handler, which makes manipulations to the content of the textbox. It is same for most of the textboxes.
How can I collate the code so that I do not have to write the same code for all the textboxes LostFocus event function.

```
private void TextBox1_LostFocus(object sender, 
                     Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextBox1.Text != "")
            {
                feet = FeetConversion(TextBox1.Text.Trim());
                TextBox1.Text = ConvertDecimalToFraction(feet);
            }
        }

private void TextBox2_LostFocus(object sender, 
                     Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
            if (TextBox2.Text != "")
            {
                feet = FeetConversion(TextBox2.Text.Trim());
                TextBox2.Text = ConvertDecimalToFraction(feet);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make all TextBox suscribe the same one handler method. Then, you could distinguish between different textboxes in the event handler method and get their text.

I made a simple code sample. The XAML looks like the following:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel">
        <TextBox></TextBox>
        <TextBox></TextBox>
        <TextBox></TextBox>
        <TextBox></TextBox>
        <TextBox></TextBox>
        <TextBox></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    foreach (var control in stackpanel.Children)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox textBox = control as TextBox;
            textBox.LostFocus += TextBox_LostFocus;
        }
    }
}

private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        if (textBox.Text !="")
        {
            feet = FeetConversion(textBox.Text.Trim());
            textBox.Text = ConvertDecimalToFraction(feet);
        }
    }
}
```